# Ошибка при обновлении сущности в EF(используются репозитории и DI)

Tags: c#, repository, di

Пытаюсь реализовать работу с БД, используя репозитории и DI (Microsoft.Extensions). В репозитории прописан следующий код:

```
public void Update(T item)
        {
            if (item is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(item));

            _db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
            
            if (AutoSaveChanges) _db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Сами репозитории зареганы в контейнере .AddTransient<>()
БД регистрируется так:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddDatabase(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration Configuration) => services
            .AddDbContext<InveTimeDB>(opt =>
            {
                var type = Configuration["Type"];
                if (type == "MSSQL") opt.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString(type));
                else throw new InvalidOperationException($"Тип подключения {type} не поддерживается");
            })
            .AddScoped<DbInitializer>()
            .AddRepositoriesInDb()
            ;
```

```
class DbInitializer
    {
        private readonly InveTimeDB _db;

        public DbInitializer(InveTimeDB db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        public async Task InitializeAsync()
        {
            await _db.Database.MigrateAsync();
        }
    }
```

При попытке обновления бросает ошибку, что сущность уже отслеживается

> The instance of entity type 'Employee' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.

Смена типа регистрации в контейнере сервисов результата не дала, изменения в методе _db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified на _db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Detached; так же результата не дала.
Мне дали совет настроить сервис так, чтобы он после использования сразу удалялся, но как это сделать я не нашёл.....
Help please!!!....

PS
Класс реализации репозитория:

```
internal class DbRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : Entity, new()
    {
        private readonly InveTimeDB _db;
        private readonly DbSet<T> _Set;


        public bool AutoSaveChanges { get; set; } = true;


        public DbRepository(InveTimeDB db)
        {
            _db = db;
            _Set = db.Set<T>();
        }



        public virtual IQueryable<T> Items => _Set;

        public T Add(T item)
        {
            if (item is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(item));
            _db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Added;
            if (AutoSaveChanges) _db.SaveChanges();
            return item;
        }

        public async Task<T> AddAsync(T item, CancellationToken Cancel = default)
        {
            if (item is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(item));
            _db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Added;
            if (AutoSaveChanges) await _db.SaveChangesAsync(Cancel).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return item;
        }

        public T Get(int id) => Items.SingleOrDefault(item => item.Id == id);

        public async Task<T> GetAsync(int id, CancellationToken Cancel = default) => await Items
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(item => item.Id == id, Cancel)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);


        public void Remove(int id)
        {
            var item = _Set.Local.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == id) ?? new T { Id = id };

            _db.Remove(item);

            if (AutoSaveChanges) _db.SaveChanges();
        }

        public async Task RemoveAsync(int id, CancellationToken Cancel = default)
        {
            var item = _Set.Local.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == id) ?? new T { Id = id };

            _db.Remove(item);

            if (AutoSaveChanges) await _db.SaveChangesAsync(Cancel).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        public void Update(T item)
        {
            if (item is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(item));

            
            //TODO: The instance of entity type 'Employee' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.

            _db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;


            if (AutoSaveChanges) _db.SaveChanges();
        }

        public async Task UpdateAsync(T item, CancellationToken Cancel = default)
        {
            if (item is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(item));
            _db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
            if (AutoSaveChanges) await _db.SaveChangesAsync(Cancel).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
```

Регистратор репозитория

```
public static class RepositoryRegistrator
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddRepositoriesInDb(this IServiceCollection services) => services
            .AddTransient<IRepository<Employee>, EmployeeRepository>()
            ;
    }
```

Команда загрузки данных

```
public async Task OnLoadEmployeesCommandExequted(object p)
        {
            EmployeesCollection = new ObservableCollection<EmpBaseInfo>(await _EmployeeRepository.Items
            .Select(e => new EmpBaseInfo
            {
                Id = e.Id,
                Name = e.Name,
                SecondName = e.SecondName,
                Patronymic = e.Patronymic,
                Phone = e.Phone,
                Email = e.Email,
                Position = e.Position
            })
            .OrderBy(p => p.SecondName)
            .ThenBy(p => p.Name)
            .ThenBy(p => p.Patronymic)
            .ToArrayAsync());
        }
```

Команда изменения сущности в БД

```
public void OnModifiEmployeeCommandExequted(object p)
        {
            var emp_to_modifi = p ?? SelectedEmployee;

            if (emp_to_modifi is not EmpBaseInfo empBase) return;

            var emp = empBase.ConvertToEmployee();

            if (!_UserDialog.EditEpmloyee(emp)) return;

            //TODO: Realise command

            _EmployeeRepository.Update(emp);  //Вот тут все и ломается
/*  пока не рассматривается. даже не помню, что я тут хотел сделать
            var item = _EmployeesCollection.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == emp.Id);
            if (item != null)
            {
                item = new EmpBaseInfo(emp);
            }
        }
*/
```

Метод диалогового окна для изменения данных сотрудника

```
public bool EditEpmloyee(Employee employee)
        {
            EmpEditorWindowViewModel employee_editor_viewModel = new(employee, _PositionRepository, _ShowPasswordWindowService);


            EmpEditorWindow employee_editor_window = new()
            {
                DataContext = employee_editor_viewModel
            };


            if (employee_editor_window.ShowDialog() != true)
            {
                return false;
            }

            employee.Id = employee_editor_viewModel.EmpId;
            employee.SecondName = employee_editor_viewModel.EmpSecondName;
            employee.Name = employee_editor_viewModel.EmpName;
            employee.Patronymic = employee_editor_viewModel.EmpPatronymic;
            employee.Phone = employee_editor_viewModel.EmpPhone;
            employee.Email = employee_editor_viewModel.EmpEmail;
            employee.Login = employee_editor_viewModel.EmpLogin;
            employee.Position = employee_editor_viewModel.SelectedPosition;

            return true;
        }
```

забыл, вот как сервисы вызваны в App:

```
 internal static void ConfigureServices(HostBuilderContext host, IServiceCollection services) => services
            .AddDatabase(host.Configuration.GetSection("Database"))
            .AddViewModels()
            .AddServices()
            ;
```

Comment: Дайте больше кода. Весь код от получения энтити до вызова `Update`

Comment: Добавлю позже, мне так же подсказали: "Проблема заключается в том, что в контексте БД уже есть объект с таким идентификатором. Надо поменять принцип взаимодействия с контекстом БД таким образом, что бы он уничтожался как можно быстрее после выполнения операций. Для этого при извлечении сервисов из IoC в контейнере можно создавать области и получать сервисы не у самого провайдера сервисов, а из созданной области. По завершении действия область надо разрушать. Тогда все сервисы и контекст БД, полученные из области, будут также разрушены."  Но вот как это реализовать, я пока не нашёл...

Comment: То есть, мне надо переписать как-то контейнер, который добавил вторым куском кода, так, чтобы после использования он разрушался.

Comment: Добавил весь код до вызова Update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предлагаю найти в контексте энтити по айди и после ее модифицировать. С точки зрения кода это будет сделать проще всего, и без рефакторинга вот этого всего...

```
// var emp = empBase.ConvertToEmployee(); заменить на ->
var emp = await _EmployeeRepository.GetAsync(empBase.Id);
```

Comment: ну это костыль.... А когда не я буду дальше писать его? лучше сейчас сделать правильно, чем потом хавать кактус....

Comment: Поясню, empBase, реализует модель с дополнительной визуализацией данных для работы+ не содержит упоминаний о пароле (пароль хранится в другой таблице, связь 1 к 1)

Comment: И простите за сумбур, голова пухнет от количества информиции

Comment: @Heksys вы изначально работаете с разными энтити. Вам надо на открытии получить ее, отобразить данные на вьюхе, модифицировать затреканную энтити в EF и просто после сохранить. При получении энтити из EF она по дефолту добавляется в ченжтрекер и EF сам следить за ее изменением

Comment: Да, вы правы. Переписал методы и все заработало)

Comment: Да и модель переписал)